# Youtube API - background play? cache?

Tags: caching, background, youtube-api, playback, multitasking

On a desktop browser (Chrome, Safari, Firefox, etc.) you can have several tabs open and have a Youtube video cached on every tab. You can playback those videos even if you dont have internet anymore (because they are cached) and also you can minimize the browser to work on other stuff (so you can listen to the audio but dont have the video open at the same time).

So my question is: can I develop an app for mobile devices, which can have Youtube videos playing in the background (multitask) and also be able to cache them, and play them offline afterwards?

I just want to do the same that a browser can do on a computer, but on an iPhone. *The Youtube API Terms os Service are not clear in this aspect.

Answer (score 1):

The terms of service are here: https://developers.google.com/youtube/terms

"For the avoidance of doubt, Your API Client shall not be designed to cache YouTube audiovisual content."